# how to prevent youtube video click go youtube site?

Tags: html, youtube

In another word,

how to make youtube click on video goes to another URL? affiliate link for example.

Thank you

Comment: in what language / platform are you creating your page?

Comment: Thanks for your response. in pure html

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can't change the default link behavior of an embedded YouTube video. Not in the `iFrame` and not in the older `object` version.

If that would work it would be a huge security vulnerability.

See these documentation articles for your possibilities on how to embed a YouTube video:

- [Embed a YouTube video](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=171780)
- [YouTube Embedded Player Parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html)